# Autoscaling in Google Cloud Dataflow is not working as expected

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to enable autoscaling in my dataflow job as described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling). I did that by setting the relevant algorithm via the following code:

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(AutoscalingAlgorithmType.THROUGHPUT_BASED)
```

After I set this and deployed my job, it always works with the max. number of CPUs available, i.e. if I set max number of workers to 10, then it uses all 10 CPUs although average CPU usage is about 50%. How does this THROUGHPUT_BASED algorithm works and where I am making mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve though. 100% CPU utilization?

Comment: I am getting some events from a Pub/Sub subscription and sometimes number of events increases, e.g. weekends. So, I want my dataflow job adapt itself to catch up with all event without latency. In this case, when I set number of workers to 5 manually there is no latency out there and CPU usage is ~90% that's why it seems that running 10 CPU should not be logical.

Comment: Seems like the full objective is given as _"The objective is to minimize backlog while maximizing worker utilization and throughput, and quickly react to spikes in load."_. It might be that at 90% CPU usage the backlog of data to process would be too big for dataflow. So it chooses a bigger number of machines which are more lightly used so the backlog is smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Although Autoscaling tries to reduce both the backlog and CPU, backlog reduction takes priority. Specific values backlog matters, Dataflow calculates 'backlog in seconds' roughly as 'backlog / throughput' and tries to keep it below 10 seconds.

In your case, I think what is preventing downscaling from 10 is due to policy regarding persistent disks (PDs) used for pipeline execution. When max workers is 10, Dataflow uses 10 persistent disks and tries to keep the number of workers at any time such that these disks are distributed roughly equally. As a consequence when the pipeline is at its max workers of 10, it tries to downscale to 5 rather than 7 or 8. In addition, it tries to keep projected CPU after downscaling to no more than 80%.

These two factors might be effectively preventing downscaling in your case. If CPU utilization is 50% with 10 workers, the projected CPU utilization is 100% for 5 workers, so it does not downscale since it is above the target 80%.

Google Dataflow is working on new execution engine that does not depend on persistent disks and does not suffer from the limitation of amout of downscaling.

A work around for this is to set higher max_workers and your pipeline might still stay at 10 or below. But that incurs a small increase in cost for PDs.

Another remote possibility is that sometimes even after upscaling estimated 'backlog seconds' might not stay below 10 seconds even with enough CPU. This could be due to various factors (user code processing, pubsub batching, etc). Would like to hear if that is affecting your pipeline.